# Trying to make a collapsible widget: How to hide/unhide all child widgets?

Tags: python, widget, pyqt

Im making a simplish widget that can act as a container for other widgets. One of the features of the widget is that you can expand/collapse it by clicking on it. My current method is basically looking up all child widgets of the layout and hiding them. I'm looking for any help on how to handle this properly - my current implementation has at least one serious caveat: that you can't add widgets while it's collapsed (they're added in an 'unhidden' state)

heres the `setCollapsed` method that is run when the widget is clicked

```
def collapsed(self):
    return self._isCollapsed
def setCollapsed(self, collapseBool):
    self._isCollapsed = collapseBool
    if self.layout()!=None:
        childWidgets = [self.layout().itemAt(i).widget() for i in range(self.layout().count())]
        for w in childWidgets:
            if isinstance(w,QtGui.QWidget):
                w.setHidden(collapseBool)
        if collapseBool:
            self._cachedMargin = self.layout().margin()
            self.layout().setMargin(0)
        else:
            self.layout().setMargin(self._cachedMargin)
```

Comment: Why would you wish to add widgets whilst the widget is closed/collapsed?

Comment: If the widgets default state in an app is collapsed, but you want to populate it on init? There's definitely ways around it. From a robustness point of view - I wouldn't want other people to be trying to use this widget without covering the most basic potential use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hiding all child widgets individually, I would just hide a single parent item.

Comment: I'll give this a try shortly, that will simplify things and seems like it should solve my "adding when collapsed" issue as well. It's so obvious now you've said it! thanks